# KStream -- iterate LIST of values and send it to output topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a below scenario

`KStream<String List<Foo> > fooList = returns me this KStream;`

now I have to send this to outputTopic one by one rather than a whole list
(i.e) fooList iterate the values alone and push them to the destination topic, so that Individual messages are pushed

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work:
`fooList.flatMapValues(v -> v).to("output");`

You can read more about `flatMapValues` here: https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#flatMapValues(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapperWithKey).

From a mathematical point of view, you asking how to flatten the `KStream` of a `List<Foo>`.  Since `flatten` is the same as the flatMap of the identify function, this ought to be what you want.

Comment: thanks, @GeoJim, I don’t know why I didn’t think of this, I was even-going through the same functionality but it didn’t strike me well enough though ,  but this is what I was expecting

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help!